# How to create a generic TypeScript interface which matches any type/interface/object with restrictions on types for values inside it?

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, types, interface

I want to create a generic TypeScript interface which matches any type or interface or object with restrictions on types for values inside it.

Here's `MyInterface` which has properties `fooIProp` and `barIProp` which stores strings with an example:

```
interface MyInterface {
  fooIProp: string;
  barIProp: string;
};

const testInterface: MyInterface = {
  fooIProp: "foo",
  barIProp:  "bar"
};
```

Here's `MyType` type alias which has properties `fooTProp` and `barTProp` which stores strings with an example:

```
type MyType = {
  fooTProp: string;
  barTProp: string;
}

const testType: MyType = {
  fooTProp: "foo",
  barTProp: "bar"
}
```

Here's an object which has properties `fooObjectKey` and `barObjectKey` which stores strings:

```
const testObject = {
  fooObjectKey: "foo",
  barObjectKey: "bar"
}
```

I create `MyGenericInterface` which accepts object with strings as keys and values as follows:

```
interface MyGenericInterface { [key: string]: string }
```

Then I try to assign `testInterface` to `MyGenericInterface`

```
const testFromInterface: MyGenericInterface = testInterface;
const testFromType: MyGenericInterface = testType;
const testFromObject: MyGenericInterface = testObject;
```

It throws TS2322 error:

```
Type 'MyInterface' is not assignable to type 'MyGenericInterface'.
  Index signature is missing in type 'MyInterface'.(2322)
```

Here's [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5rycgbwChlkYB7czABSnIAcAuZAZzClAHMBuE5AIzhQadJq3ZdeAX15EE5EG2SQ22SLEQRmGNbk3IAvIT4UqtBswBEpywBo+g4ebHJLjy0RlEiYdPRQYACp+KEbEpKaBzsxsHCA8DkJRojES8dLe8opgyhBswf7a6AWhxhGUyRauNvakjpVibkIeUpkKSipgAPL8AFYQCDlhJpQ9-YMA0hDoVjWJUGMDYFMzru6e3qDqeAHoAOIQINDACLoa+ATIANoA1tOpcZwAug9cyK1y7TmdAGJ0ALZnHZFA5HDinHDnUqdIGaXhZDp5MB-cj-Eogw7HCHbfRGToleFfXJsFH-RaDDFgk6w-B4pHksDcIA) for reference.

**Question**: How can I create a generic TypeScript interface which matches any type/interface/object with restrictions on types for values inside it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a known issue (and currently working as intended) that [implicit index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#implicit-index-signatures) are not added to values of an `interface` type, whereas they are added for anonymous object types.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#15300](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300) for discussion.

---

Technically speaking it is not safe to add implicit index signatures this way.  Object types in TypeScript are open/extendible and not closed/exact (see [microsoft/TypeScript#12936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936) for discussion/request for exact types), so it's always possible to have properties in addition to the *known* properties mentioned in the interface:

```
const someObject = {
  fooIProp: "foo",
  barIProp: "bar",
  baz: 12345
};
const unexpectedMyInterface: MyInterface = someObject; // no error
```

(although if you try to add such unknown properties directly in an annotated object literal you will get [excess property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) warnings, which sometimes makes object types in TypeScript *seem* exact when they are not).

The fact that `unexpectedMyInterface` is assignable to `MyInterface` but not to `MyGenericInterface` is why it is technically correct to prohibit the assignment.  Of course you can go through the same exercise with `MyType`:

```
const someOtherObject = {
  fooTProp: "foo",
  barTProp: "bar",
  baz: 12345
};
const unexpectedMyType: MyType = someOtherObject;
```

...yet the bad assignment of `unexpectedMyType` to `MyGenericInterface` is *allowed*:

```
const badMyGenericInterface: MyGenericInterface = unexpectedMyType;
console.log(badMyGenericInterface.baz?.toUpperCase()); // no error in TS, but 
// RUNTIME  badMyGenericInterface.baz.toUpperCase is not a function
```

---

So, what gives?  It seems to be a tradeoff.  It is [considered "safer"](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300#issuecomment-332366024) to allow this for anonymous object types and not interface types because interface types can be augmented or merged later, while anonymous object types can't be.

Personally I don't see it as much safer for one than the other.  If you want to see implicit index signatures apply to interface types also, then you might want to go to microsoft/TypeScript#15300 and give it a .

---

Until and unless that feature gets implemented, all you can have is workarounds.  One is to use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) to convert a value of `MyInterface` to an object type equivalent before assigning it to `MyGenericInterface`:

```
type Id<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] } // change interface to mapped type version
type MyInterfaceAsType = Id<MyInterface>;
const testFromInterface2: MyGenericInterface = testInterface as MyInterfaceAsType
const testInterfaceAnonymousTypeVersion: MyInterfaceAsType = testInterface;
const testFromInterface3: MyGenericInterface = testInterfaceAnonymousTypeVersion;
```

There may be other workarounds but I'd need to see more of a use case before spending too much time suggesting them.  Where are you seeing failures you'd like to fix?

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5rycgbwChlkYB7czABSnIAcAuZAZzClAHMBuE5AIzhQadJq3ZdeAX15EE5EG2SQ22SLEQRmGNbk3IAvIT4UqtBswBEpywBo+g4ebGXHlojKJEw6eigwAKr4oRsSkpgHOzGwcIDwOQpGi0RJx0l7yimDKEGxBftro+SHG4ZRJFsjWlHYJUBUubh4ZCkoqYADy-ABWEAjZocgmlF29-QDSEOhWNvakjqN9YJPTVU1SXqDqeP7oAOIQINDACLoa+ATIANoA1lMpsZwAug9cyBstWazkALYQi-1DKUyJQRJVquRavMhGDGkIoQI4AAvZgARgATABmAAsAFYPLxMkoAK5HAAefn6EAAJjocOctGgsPSdkCWL9-j0ltxkAB6XnIEDkZDQOhQLw+PxoTBAunbTSfJTsv4dMAAC2gAIGwIiUSqszqDSsbjmiJRyAxOPxniJ2VJEApSxpgWChWKbI5qo1UC1hNa2UEtP2h2OpxZmkKByOHDD8vwRntjqpQeKfsU5AANhAAHQZ8icAAUgYwUdDZx22cESIA-NmwOQAKr0PxQADCcBYEALAEpuzz+YLhaLyFBkKBkAEAMq2ATE7JEAcAJQbADkAphUABRZCAXg3AKU7iKDpZj5c0leRdcbzeg7c7Y5Yg+ycDIpP6wAUiuy7QAYnQfqekEjEMT3DeMclUUCIDTNpcjAX9fmKIDoxOACSnaVM5H9cC4L-LUkLLSCgXaX0JWCZBMGpAAeAIAD4gUuK5xjHEBkDudByBgCcXgnRinnePkBQQNU4DiFAtj0fB62QH44GvallDIgA3aAWHfEBvDIuUJIgABBFh3SMCjKK0hkaOgr9YPg-9IPRfCQLjNDYNQ5AOyZVC9OKTCvnadyhRAdAfnIYl9OCAA1FS1MKdyQqlIwfMg8zsKs1DMTslDCLipzIJ0vyAqCmKIHCqBVIUXggA)

Comment: The use case is narrower types discussed in https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/1647